# Load an assembly on a separate thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a .net assembly (from BMC remedy, if that helps), that seems to be defective by design regarding multithreading. It seems to initialize all objects on the main (UI) thread, regardless of the thread that actually constructs them, and then the usual cross-thread problems ensue.

Is there any way that I can load the assembly on a separate thread?

Comment: Maybe I did not get the question, but an assembly is not loaded on a thread, but on a process / AppDomain.

Comment: @Florian: The problem I face is that my UI thread freezes every time I perform any long running operation on *any* instance of a class from the assembly in question. Is there no way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this an answer, because I think I got your point now:

On which thread a method is executed depends on the caller of the method, not on the thread its instance was created on.

So to prevent your UI thread from freeezing you have to *start* the operation on another thread. There are tons of resources about this topic on the web.

Comment: I did start the methods in a `backgroundworker`. I have had no issues with other assemblies, just this one. Maybe I could load it later, as opposed to on the start of the project?

Comment: As I said, it makes no difference on which thread or when the assembly is loaded. Maybe the methods you call do synchronize to the UI thread?

Comment: That was the case. Thanks. It turns out that the method I was calling had a line using `Dispatcher.Invoke` somewhere. I essentially rewrote the code, and the problem was fixed.

Comment: It does matter on which thread it is loaded. If you load heavy assemblies on the UI thread, you will get glitches.